# #1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' mysql -5.7 and ubuntu-16.04

Tags: apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am getting below error while logged into the phpmyadmin.

it is not a fresh installation.

I have also tried login through the command line.

1.

```
mysql -u root -p

 **error :** ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

2.

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

I am successfully login into mysql using above command.

but not with case 1.

```
Mysql details:
username : root 
password :
```

Comment: [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42742610/5088142) should solve your problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the above problem with setting the plugin value in user tables

```
mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;

$ service mysql restart
```

Comment: And how did you log in mysql to use the command `USE mysql`? This is catch 22.

Comment: using this command sudo mysql -u root -p

Answer (score 7):

This is because MySQL by default use local system account to login as user root. This is done with plugin “unix_socket” or it might possible that password has been changed.

To allow MySQL user root to login to PhpMyAdmin, run following commands in MySQL command prompt

```
use mysql;
UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

see [PhpMyAdmin](https://blog.hostonnet.com/phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 4):

step 1. `sudo mysql -u root -p`

step 2. `USE mysql;`

step 3. `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'admin';`

Here '`admin`' is your new password,  yo can change it.

step 4. `exit`
Thanks. You are done.

Comment: Worked for me !!!

Comment: This helped me <3